# Is there a way to get a fixed number of random rows from an SQL table while allowing for repetions

Tags: sql, random, repeat

For the example here we will use the table NAMES and I need 3 rows returned.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha |
| 2 | Beta |
| 3 | Chi |
| 4 | Delta |
| 5 | Epsilon |

I know the code `SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;` will return 3 randomized rows. But it is exclusively three different rows.

Is there a way to in a query get three rows that do not influence each other, and thus allow for repetion? So a result could be Beta, Alpha, Delta. Or Beta, Epsilon, Beta, or even Beta, Beta, Beta.

Comment: `union all` 3 individual queries, each limited to 1 row.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try achieving this via independent subqueries that are stitched together using `union all`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, name FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) d
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, name FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) d
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, name FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) d
```

Note: I recommend you don't rely solely on "select *", specify the columns you need.

Try running it here (using Postgres) more than once: https://dbfiddle.uk/IwNV0z34

Another method would be to multiply the number of rows by the wanted sample size (here it is 3) using a cross join then selecting from that:

```
select
    id, name, cj.n
from names
cross join (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3) cj
order by rand()
limit 3
```

see both methods working here: https://dbfiddle.uk/bhBLmOSv

nb: random() is used in the fiddles as the alternative to rand()